# Как получить контекст Nuxt.js в функции из файла .js?

Tags: javascript, static, nuxt.js, this, assets

Хочу вынести все обращения к API через axios в отдельные js файлы в Nuxt.js

Axios это модуль идущий вместе с Nuxt.js. В файле nuxt.config.js для него указываются настройки.

Сделал файл js:

```
export default {
  findAll: () => {
    console.log(this)
    this.$axios.get(`/forms/lists/parameters`).then(result => {return result.data})

  }
}
```

Дальше в компоненте(страница) добавляю этот файл:

```
<script>
  import ParameterAPI from '~/assets/js/API/parameter'

  export default {
    //...
    methods: {
      readData() {
        let responseData = ParameterAPI.findAll()
        console.log(responseData)
    }
  }
<script>
```

Внутри функции findAll this неопределен. Пробовал определять как function this содержит контекст функции, а не компонента Nuxt.js.

Как добиваться, чтобы в функции из файла js вызываемой в компонентах Nuxt.js был доступен правильный контекст this?

P.S. Может есть более правильный способ добавлять js файлы?

Comment: забинли контекст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

забинди контекст

```
<script>
      import ParameterAPI from '~/assets/js/API/parameter'

      export default {
        //...
        methods: {
          readData() {
            let responseData = ParameterAPI.findAll.call(this)
            console.log(responseData)
        }
      }
    <script>
```

Comment: Acolon а саму функцию findAll надо из стрелочной переделать в function()? У меня со стрелочной выдает ошибку.

Comment: а что за ошибка. у стрелочных как бы не нет контекста.

Comment: this не определен, т.е. контекст не привязывается к стрелочной функции. Видимо так как у них его нет и привязать его к ним тоже нельзя. Только если внешний контекст.